# Is it possible to synchronise TFS work items with outlook or sharepoint tasks?

Tags: tasks, tfs, task-management

Is there any integration between Team Foundation Server work items and tasks in either sharepoint or outlook?

Comment: Either use http://www.teamcompanion.com/ or code your own from the TFS API from scratch.

Comment: What do you mean saying integration with outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Not tried this myself, but looks like it's got more than you need, calendar and email as well as tasks (plus source code):

http://bowie.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can create tfs work items that are linked to Outlook objects using TMO. I think this is what you want to achieve. More information and download here - https://gotmo.co.uk